# Best AWS Instance for Partitioning Big Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

the problem that I am having right now is trying to find the best AWS instance for partitioning large data (scaling to greater than 1TB).
The data that I am receiving is structured data, and am hoping to partition it by either /year/month/day/ or /year/month/day/hour of the created at time. So far I have tried using EMR with the following configurations to partition 260GB of parquet data in /year/month/day (spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled == true):

3 r5.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 64GB) --> > 1 hour to just write to HDFS
2 c5.4xlarge (16 vCPU, 32GB) --> >> 1 hour to just write to HDFS (was 28% slower than the 3 r5.2xlarge)

2 r5d.4xlarge (16 vCPU, 128GB) --> 54 minutes to just write to HDFS (note, HDFS is on NVMe SSD)

This is a graph of what the **3 r5.2xlarge** is producing:
[image]

This is a graph of what the **2 c5.4xlarge** is producing (note, the two peaks are due to running the job twice):
[image]

This is a graph of what the **2 r5d.4xlarge** is producing:
[image: desc.]

Is it possible for me to reach ~10 minutes? If so, would that mean adding more nodes or a different instance type?